Too long FAISS execution
I have the code:
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS

codex = 'Some very very VERY long string'

chunk_size = 750
chunk_overlap = chunk_size // 25 
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=chunk_size, chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
docs = text_splitter.create_documents([codex])

modelPath = "intfloat/multilingual-e5-large"

model_kwargs = {'device': 'cuda'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=modelPath,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)


And after that I tried to get a vector database:
db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
But this part of code is executed very long (After 2 hours I've lost my patience and abort it)
How can I make it faster?
At first python reccomend me to install faiss-cpu. I tried install gpu version but not succeed.

Do you have a GPU? If so I recommend loading model in GPU.  What was the error when installing faiss-cpu? This might help
